# Runtime error : DBSQL_SQL_ERROR exception : CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB, where to focus?

Tags: abap

More info from stms :

```
Short Text
SQL error "SQL code: -10108" occurred while accessing table "CDHDR".


What happened?
Database error text: "SQL message: Session has been reconnected."
Return value of the database layer: "SQL dbsl rc: 99"
```

The problem is that client is running this code through the job in which I am not available to debug it. All I know is that it is working for other countries selected but for some specific it is not so the question is : 
Was it a temporary connection error between two servers or is it data overload issue due to SELECT statement?

[image]

At the moment I am not really sure which thing I have to look on the system, the same program once produced the error for exceeding the limit in the db query ( > 10 minutes) so this might be related to system configuration or what?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the context around the `SELECT` in the the ~1500 lines not shown in your screenshot? Are you having some kind of loop around it that opens DB connections? Any more entries in error log transaction `st22`?

Comment: Hi, just a normal code flow, this is the start of the FORM and after that, it is using new SELECT, etc, the problem is that client had 3 jobs with the same variant, two of them worked and one isn't but I don't  know why

Comment: It's a SQL error, at database level, so you should indicate what database you are using. If it's HANA, see note [2222200 - FAQ: SAP HANA Network](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2222200) how to troubleshoot error -10108, and open a ticket at SAP support if it doesn't solve.

Comment: yep, seems to be basis-related error and your DB-stack was improperly configured